# CREATE DATABASE AS COPY does not work with Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure

I'm new with T-SQL and MSSQL but need to copy Azure SQL database from one server to another.

As I googled [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-copy-transact-sql/) - it can be done with a `CREATE DATABASE Database1_copy AS COPY OF server1.Database1;` query, but in my Vusial Studio Code editor on the Ubuntu Linux with the `vscode-mssql` extention - I have an error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'database'.

My full query looks next:

```
CREATE DATABASE Database1_copy AS COPY OF oldserver.database.windows.net.olddatabasenamehere;
```

Additional googling leads me to the same solutions ([here](http://blog.idera.com/sql-server/how-to-make-a-copy-of-a-database-on-windows-azure-sql-database/) is another example I found).

What I'm doing wrong here?

I understood that even the first link published on Azure's resource (azure.microsoft.com) - it does not necessarily is working solution for Azure's SQL.

P.S. Idea is to automate DEV environment rollout (with ARM templates) as a copy of the current Live environment, with creating databases as a copy of Live's databases.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [**BOL**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn268335.aspx) :

> The AS COPY OF argument does **not support the fully qualified unique domain names**. In other words, if your server's fully qualified domain name is `serverName.database.windows.net`, **use only `serverName` during database copy.**

So your command should be

```
CREATE DATABASE Database1_copy AS COPY OF oldserver.olddatabasenamehere;
```

Comment: Thanks - this works. A bit weird for me. First I added `111.111.222.222 oldserverentry` to my `/etc/hosts` file and tried to connect to - but got a message like "_The remote partner server name 'oldserverentry.database.windows.net' could not be resolved._". Not sure where this replacement was done. Nevertheless  - I successfully connected with `oldserver.olddatabasenamehere;`. 
Although now I have "_Partner server 'oldserver' is not compatible with server_" error, but that's another issue (hello, Azure).

Answer (score 1):

Apart from running:

```
CREATE DATABASE mydbcopy AS COPY OF server1.mydb
```

which is a great command to know (my thanks goes to Kbdavis07 and Kin Shah).

One must remember to also run

```
CREATE USER [mydbcopy-developers] from external provider 
ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [mydbcopy-developers]
```

to ensure that other AAD users can access the database.
SQL Logins also become orphaned, and they can be fixed like this:

```
ALTER USER mySQLlogin WITH Login = mySQLlogin
```

if my sql login was called mySQLlogin, and already existed in the Master database.
The information can be found here, if you look hard enough: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-copy

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose server and database name in []

```
CREATE DATABASE Database1_copy AS COPY OF [oldserver].[olddatabasenamehere];
```

Otherwise it won't work.

You can also check the status by running this:

```
    SELECT TOP (1000) [session_activity_id]
      ,[resource_type]
      ,[resource_type_desc]
      ,[major_resource_id]
      ,[minor_resource_id]
      ,[operation]
      ,[state]
      ,[state_desc]
      ,[percent_complete]
      ,[error_code]
      ,[error_desc]
      ,[error_severity]
      ,[error_state]
      ,[start_time]
      ,[last_modify_time]
  FROM [sys].[dm_operation_status]
```

All from your Master Database of your "New" Target Server.